# System accounting misbehaviour on MacOS X (Yosemite)?

Tags: kernel, timestamps

On all my Unixes (CentOS, FreeBSD, MacOS X) I activate the system accounting as a basic security rule.

On MacOS X (Yosemite, 10.10.3) I see a misbehaviour I am investigating to fix.

Everytime I run `lastcomm` to analyze a recent set of processes terminated I find processes really terminated but with dates coming from the future as in this example:

```
••My_Mac••$ lastcomm | more
lastcomm   -X      bob      ttys007    0.00 secs Mon Jul 26 14:13 (0:00:03.05)
more       -       bob      ttys007    0.00 secs Mon Jul 26 14:13 (0:00:03.05)
stty       -       bob      ttys007    0.00 secs Mon Jul 26 14:13 (0:00:00.05)
path_helpe -       bob      ttys007    0.00 secs Mon Jul 26 14:13 (0:00:00.50)
sshd       -SF     _sshd    __         0.00 secs Mon Jan 27 17:31 (0:00:04.91)
procmail   -S      bob      __         0.00 secs Mon Jul 26 14:11 (0:00:00.09)
cron       -F      root     __         0.00 secs Mon Jun  1 13:10 (0:00:00.33)
sendmail   -S      root     __         0.00 secs Mon Jun  1 13:10 (0:00:00.31)
postdrop   -       root     __         0.00 secs Mon Jun  1 13:10 (0:00:00.09)
[...]
••My_Mac••$ date
Mon Jun  1 13:12:07 CEST 2015
••My_Mac••$
```

At first, the problem isn't as simple as a timezone error:

Jul 26, 14:13 (wrong timestamp) and Jun 1, 13:10 (correct timestamp) are many days appart.

This isn't either a huge time drift caused by a `date` erroneous use. Moreover this server is `ntp` synchronized on a strate 1 `ntp` server.

---

Did someone else see the same misbehaviour?
Do you see a path to better investigate this problem?
Is this a known bug?

Comment: Same behavior here (OS X 10.10.3 "Yosemite"): `bash       -F      jaume    ttys001    0.00 secs Mon Jul 26 21:37 (0:00:00.00)
sudo       -S      root     ttys001    0.00 secs Mon Jun  1 20:35 (0:00:00.02)`.It is interesting to note that times seem to be reported correctly if the user that owns the process is root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found same misbehavior on ElCapitan (MacOSX 10.11..).  On investigation, saw that timestamp data in /var/account/acct file was correct.  Compiling source of lastcomm.c in
http://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-187.tar.gz
showed compiler message "warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'u_int32_t *' (aka 'unsigned int *') to parameter of type 'const time_t *' (aka 'const long *')"
 
The following patch to fix bad accounting timestamp worked for me in ElCapitan.  It may work for Yosemite (10.10..) and earlier.

```
*** lastcomm.c  2016/08/26 19:44:23 1.1
--- lastcomm.c  2016/08/27 00:30:49 1.2
***************
*** 135,138 ****
--- 135,140 ----
        if (!*argv || requested(argv, &ab)) {

+           time_t timelong;
+           timelong = ab.ac_btime;
            t = expand(ab.ac_utime) + expand(ab.ac_stime);
            (void)printf(
***************
*** 144,148 ****
                 user_from_uid(ab.ac_uid, 0), UT_LINESIZE,
                 UT_LINESIZE, getdev(ab.ac_tty),
!                t / (double)AHZ, ctime(&ab.ac_btime));
            delta = expand(ab.ac_etime) / (double)AHZ;
            printf(" (%1.0f:%02.0f:%05.2f)\n",
--- 146,150 ----
                 user_from_uid(ab.ac_uid, 0), UT_LINESIZE,
                 UT_LINESIZE, getdev(ab.ac_tty),
!                t / (double)AHZ, ctime(&timelong));
            delta = expand(ab.ac_etime) / (double)AHZ;
            printf(" (%1.0f:%02.0f:%05.2f)\n",
```

Comment: I don't have a Mac to test it but that could be a valid answer.  You should remove the other one or integrate it to this one.

Comment: Patch correct. Tested on Yosemite 10.10.5: OK.
I advise you to provide it to Apple.

Comment: Apple Bug Reporter entry submitted with number 28056519